# Spring 3 MVC And JSR303 @Valid return null values

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

I new in Spring, I`m attempting to create simple form example, and i have a problem

When I click on submit and receive input values and valid them, in controller:

```
@Valid Student student
```

I have always null values... I try to change mapping, read post [Spring MVC form input value is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052594/spring-mvc-form-input-value-is-always-null) but nothing helps :(

My controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/rejestracja"})
public class RejestracjaController {

@Autowired
private StudentService studentService;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String rejestracjaSetup (Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("student",new Student());
    return "rejestracjaPage";
}


@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String dodajStuenta (@Valid Student student, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    System.out.println("------");
    System.out.print(student.getFirstname());
    System.out.print("=====");
    System.out.print(student.getLastname());
    System.out.print("=====");
    System.out.print(student.getYearLevel());
    System.out.print("=====");
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "rejestracjaPage";
    }
    return "redirect:/list";
}
}
```

My .jsp:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="student">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First name</td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="firstname"/>
            <form:errors path="firstname"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Last name</td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="lastname"/>
            <form:errors path="lastname"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>yearLevel</td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="yearLevel"/>
            <form:errors path="yearLevel"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Register"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

And Model:

```
@Entity
public class Student {

@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int studentId;

@Column
@NotNull
    @Size(min = 6)
private String firstname;

@Column
@Length(min=3, max=50, message="Example message1")
private String lastname;

@Column
@Min(value = 1, message = "Example message2")
private int yearLevel;

public Student() {
}

   ....
    getters and setters
   .... 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of your `dodajStuenta()` controller method?

Comment: Does it actually look like `------null=====null=====null=====`?

Comment: Yes this like looks "------null=====null=====null====="

Comment: Did you declare the tag lib in your JSP?

Comment: do you have hibernate-validator in your classpath ?

Answer (score 0):

Validation is not (yet) your problem. Your problem is that empty `Student` bean. Try to bind it with `@ModelAttribute`:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String dodajStuenta (
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student,
        BindingResult bindingResult) {

}
```